# Are elements guaranteed to return in the order they appear in DOM?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm using `WebdriverIO` to drive my Selenium server, but I was curious if there is a guarantee in the Selenium spec, or in the CSS spec that guarantees elements are returned in the order they are found appearing on the page.

For instance:

```
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

If I were to do `driver.getText('li');`, am I guaranteed that it will return:

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

Or are there cases where the behavior will be undefined? Maybe also, what sort of behavior should I expect? I suppose it's probably a depth first search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the order is guaranteed by the [WebDriver specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#element-location-strategies):

> All element location strategies must return elements in the order in which they appear in the current document.

Comment: Tremendous, I'll have to read this top to bottom. Interesting how that also answers whether it's a breadth or depth first traversal.

Comment: Wow! that's one of the questions I had too. Thanks to both of you

Comment: @Breedly FYI, I've fixed the link (now it points to a fresh spec). Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the specification helps a lot in understanding how webdriver works internally. For instance, I had a nice journey into how visibility of an element is determined: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#element-displayedness.

Comment: @alecxe I wonder if the pop up windows are also ordered accordingly

Comment: @Saifur interesting, do you mean the order of the window handles in the list?

Comment: Correct. I actually encountered an issue with window handles recently where I did not want to close the original window handle but the rest. I had to write some junky code just to make sure that I do not close the original. I hope the order is guaranteed

Comment: @Saifur yeah, no order for window handles: it says `The Get Window Handle command returns a list of window handles for every open top-level browsing context. The order in which the window handles are returned is arbitary.`